# Elasticsearch and word_delimiter token filter

Tags: elasticsearch, delimiter, cpu-word

I have been reading this documentation from elasticsearch: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html

And at the same was searching the internet for examples.
Unfortunately not just there were a few examples most of them doesn't work.

I would really appreciate it if someone can post or give an example on how to use word_delimeter token filter in elasticsearch.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what you want done?

Comment: Hello @paqash, thanks for taking interest on my question. user3775217 has provided a good example below which is very helpful. But I would be happy if you can give me an example where if I insert the document that has a text **{"name" : "everybody"}** and if search the string "**every**" or "**body**", the result will be at least that document . Basically I wanted to see elasticsearch feature "**generate_word_parts**" in action. Here is similar question I have posted earlier: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336347/elasticsearch-token-filter-word-delimiter-and-generate-word-parts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticversion - 5.2

Try the following mappings

```
PUT demo
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "index_analyzer_v1" : {
              "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
              "filter" : [ "word_delimeter"]
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "ngram_filter" : {
              "type" : "nGram",
              "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
            },
            "word_delimeter" : {
              "type" : "word_delimiter",
              "generate_number_parts" : true,
              "catenate_words" : true,
              "catenate_numbers": true,
              "preserve_original" : true,
              "stem_english_possessive": true

            },
            "stop_words" : {
              "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": ["and", "is", "the", "we", "in", "are", "was", "were", "of"]
            }
          }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
            "product": {
                "dynamic": "strict",
                "properties": {
                  "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "index_analyzer_v1"
                  }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Index the following document

```
POST demo/product
{
  "name":"SH-09"
}
```

Run the following query

```
POST demo/_search
{
  "query": {"bool": {"must": [
    {"term": {
      "name": {
        "value": "09"
      }
    }}
  ]}}
}
```

Furthur more if you want to see the values stored in inverted index, run the following query

```
GET demo/_analyze?analyzer=index_analyzer_v1&text=SH-09
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot @user3775217. Your example works (in both 1.7.5 and 5.2.1) specially on the example document you have posted. But I did try adding {"name":"everybody"} and searched for "body" or "every" but it didn't work. I am actually wanted to see the feature/flag "generate_number_parts" in action. But all good man. I really appreciate your answer. Thanks a lot =)!

Answer (score 0):

I know this questions is old, but anyways...
I cant comment because i dont have reputation points, but if you try to search "everybody" there is no "-" as provided in the above answer,if you want to search "body" in "everybody" maybe a simple wildcard would help you.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

i hope it was usefull